# How can I passing messages of STL object in C++ such as std::map in MPI?

Tags: c++, stl, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to communicate stl objects in C++ such as `std::map` and `std::list` using MPI, but I do not know how to make it.

Comment: See if [these](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.skeleton_and_content) features of `Boost.MPI` can be of use to you.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this isn't possible directly. You will need to do some sort of serialization.

Since you are mentioning MPI, you are probably interested in high performance. In such case using serialization probably isn't the best idea. So I would stay away from more complicated STL structures and work only with `std::vector`.